# R Get Characters Between Brackets In a String

Tags: r, string, select, character

I want to get characters between brackets.

Here is an example of my data.

```
[ADAM SMITH] update status of [34BND001] . Status [AVAILABLE => OUT_OF_SERVICE (dirty)]
```

Wanted output: `34BND001`

Thank you,

Comment: `ADAM SMITH` and `AVAILABLE => OUT_OF_SERVICE (dirty)` are also characters in brackets. You need to elaborate and provide a better example of your data and specify what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` and match it with regex.  Here, we use a regex lookaround (`(?<=\\[`) that matches the `[` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) and characters that are not a `]` (`[^]]+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "(?<=\\[)\\d+[^]]+")
#[1] "34BND001"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "[ADAM SMITH] update status of [34BND001] . Status [AVAILABLE => OUT_OF_SERVICE (dirty)]"
```

To known this expressions you can search further about regex (regular expressions)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want a better understading of this part: ```(?<=\\[)\\d+[^]]+")```  What should i search for a knowledge of that part. Can you help me?

Comment: @EceÖzçınar  Sorry i forgot to update.  I have added some description.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you again it helped a lot